# Find a conformal map 2

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

> $\textbf{Exercise}$ Find a conformal mapping which maps the domain $D$ onto the open unit disc, where $D$ is the intersection of $\vert z \vert <1 $ and $\vert z-1 \vert <1 $.

I knew that Mobius Transformation is a self-conformal map on the open unit disc. However, I don't know how to find a conformal map when two regions intersect...

Any help is appreciated...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $D$ has two corners that somehow have to be straightened by the map. Construct your map in several steps:

- The two circles intersect in two points $p$, $q$. Find a Moebius transformation $T$ that maps these two points to $0$ and $\infty$. Such a $T$ will map the two circles to a pair of lines through $0$, hence $D$ to a wedge. Determine the opening angle of this wedge.
- A second map of the form $w\mapsto w^\lambda$ with a suitable $\lambda>0$ will map the wedge to a half plane.
- Map this half plane to the unit disc by a suitable Moebius transformation.

Comment: I found two points $1/2 + i \sqrt {3}/2 , 1/2 - i\sqrt{3}/2 $ . Thus, If T be  $(az+b)/(cz+d)$, $-b/a = 1/2 - i  \sqrt {3} /2 , -d/c = 1/2 + i \sqrt {3} /2 $. Then, $T(1) \neq 0 $.... How to find a Moebius transformation??..

Comment: I thought the opening angle of this wedge is $ 2 / 3 \pi $

Comment: Ah.... Sorry... I found $ T = \frac{(1-\sqrt{3} i) +1+\sqrt{3}i}{(1+\sqrt{3}i)z+1-\sqrt{3}i}$. $\lambda = 3/2 $ and we knew  $F(z)=\frac{i-z}{i+z}$ map from the upper half plane to the unit disk. I got it! Thank you!